# MAUI Android tablet not detected, can't activate tethering

Tags: maui, maui-android

**I want to debug my MAUI app on an Android device.**
The Android API version is in the allowed range.
I connect the device to the PC where I use Visual Studio.
Developer options are enabled.
USB debugging is enabled.
I go to Tethering & Mobile Hotspot and enable USB tethering.
**The tethering switch immediately goes back to off.**
The device does not appear in the Visual Studio selection of debug devices.

I tried with different USB cable and get the same issue.

**How can I get the tethering working respectively how can I debug on my device?**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Tethering and Mobile hot spot.

Usually you do:

1. Enable USB debugging.
2. And in Settings you set "Use USB to" to Transfer files.
   (You will have notification, that when you click on it, it brings you there)

Sometimes you have nice options like:
"Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode"
So you don't even have to set it.

Sometimes you need additional confirmation dialog that will pop on your device, that will request from you authenticate the connection. (Click "Allow")

And this is not really relevant those days, but without drivers you cannot do anything. Luckily all you have to do is plug your device, set the mode, and it will download them automatically. (I assume Windows OS).

Tetherings and Hotspots are something else.